# implementing onClickListener in custom class

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to implement a custom toggle button class on which touch events can be identified using the onClickListener

However if I put in any code in the overridden onClick() method, the app crashes. What might be the problem?

My custom class is as given below:

```
package com.example.buttoncontrollertest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ButtonController extends ToggleButton implements OnClickListener{

    public static final int UPDATE_LED_SETTING = 1;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Handler uiHandler;

    public ButtonController(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ButtonController(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ButtonController(Context context,AttributeSet attrs, int i){
        super(context,attrs,i);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        enabled = false;
        this.setChecked(false);
        this.setEnabled(false);
        super.setOnClickListener(this);
        uiHandler = null;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler){
        uiHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean en){
        enabled=en;
        super.setEnabled(en);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText((Context)getApplicationWindowToken(), "button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }       
}
```

I cannot use a direct ToggleButton since this new class is also supposed to do a lot of other stuff

The following is the error log:

```
04-15 11:10:14.904: D/libEGL(7836): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 11:10:14.912: D/libEGL(7836): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 11:10:14.920: D/libEGL(7836): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
04-15 11:10:15.021: D/OpenGLRenderer(7836): Enabling debug mode 0
04-15 11:10:22.896: D/~~~~(7836): ~~~~ button pressed
04-15 11:10:22.896: D/AndroidRuntime(7836): Shutting down VM
04-15 11:10:22.896: W/dalvikvm(7836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4144d2a0)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl$W cannot be cast to android.content.Context
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at com.example.buttoncontrollertest.ButtonController.onClick(ButtonController.java:70)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17337)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-15 11:10:22.896: E/AndroidRuntime(7836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what problem you are getting currently ?

Comment: Do not make a Toast, add logging instead: `Log.d("~~~~","\n\n~~~~ button pressed");` You cannot debug Android code without logging.

Comment: using Log works, but not if I try to add any other code inside. What is the issue with using Toast? Since I eventually have to use the app with a hardware accessory so I cannot keep it connected to the computer via USB

Comment: I think the Issue may be you are trying to aceess some UI Elements other than Currently Loaded Activity Class, So better to USE AsyncTask to CAll ur ToggleButtonClass from ur Activity Class

Comment: I have added the error log output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of (Context)getApplicationWindowToken() you should use getContext().